# Formatting indian rupees in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to format the Indian rupees like mentioned below.

> **eg.87,15,725**
>
> **eg.1,37,15,725**
>
> **eg.47,624**

`StringFormat={}{0:#\,#}}"` I was tried to set this property to `TextBlcok`, but I am value like

> 53,000,000.

I need to format the `TextBlock` as 5,30,00,000
Before Last 3 digits i want comma(,)
what would be the `StringFormat` for the same.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify your culture code so it will look something like below:

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture=hi-IN}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but, your condition still not matching to requirement. @Cubicle.Jockey Can you provide any other format for same. Done lot of R&D but still not found any useful stuff.